# How to unsort key:value pairs with structlog in plain console mode?

Tags: python, django, structlog

I use `structlog` with Django and noticed that `key:value` pairs output is alphabetical in console mode, which means that when I bind a new key beginning with `_` like `log.bind('_id'=id)` then it is added at the very first.

I'm asking this question because after a new `key:value` pair is inserted in the middle or at the beginning of the line the benefit of a nicely structured and colored log is lost when reading the console.

The documentation mentions a processor boolean parameter `sort_keys` but it's not supported by the `key_value` formatter. How can I unsort key:value pairs based in plain console?

This is my config:

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "json_formatter": {
            "()": structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter,
            "processor": structlog.processors.JSONRenderer(sort_keys=False),
        },
        "plain_console": {
            "()": structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter,
            "processor": structlog.dev.ConsoleRenderer(pad_event=43,
                                                       colors=True,
                                                       force_colors=True
                                                       ),
        },
        "key_value": {
            "()": structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter,
            "processor": structlog.processors.KeyValueRenderer(
                key_order=['timestamp', 'level', 'logger', 'event'],
                sort_keys=False
            ),
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "plain_console",
        },
        "json_file": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler",
            "filename": "json.log",
            "formatter": "json_formatter",
        },
        "flat_line_file": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler",
            "filename": "flat_line.log",
            "formatter": "key_value",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        '': {
            "handlers": ["console", "flat_line_file", "json_file"],
            "level": "WARNING",
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'app1': {
            "handlers": ["console", "flat_line_file", "json_file"],
            "level": "INFO",
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'app2': {
            "handlers": ["console", "flat_line_file", "json_file"],
            "level": "INFO",
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'app3': {
            "handlers": ["console", "flat_line_file", "json_file"],
            "level": "INFO",
            'propagate': False,
        }
    }
}

structlog.configure(
    processors=[
        structlog.stdlib.filter_by_level,
        structlog.processors.TimeStamper(fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"),  # (fmt="iso"),
        structlog.stdlib.add_logger_name,
        structlog.stdlib.add_log_level,
        structlog.stdlib.PositionalArgumentsFormatter(),
        structlog.processors.StackInfoRenderer(),
        structlog.processors.format_exc_info,
        structlog.processors.UnicodeDecoder(),
        structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter.wrap_for_formatter,
    ],
    context_class=structlog.threadlocal.wrap_dict(dict),
    logger_factory=structlog.stdlib.LoggerFactory(),
    wrapper_class=structlog.stdlib.BoundLogger,
    cache_logger_on_first_use=True,
)
```

Comment: You're gonna have to be a bit more specific. I see three formatters in your config, which one do you want to affect? Also: which Python version are you running?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of specification, I would like to `sort_key=False` the `plain_console` formatter since it supports `colors=True` so it's the one I use the most. The reason I'm asking this question is because I found hard to read log flow when order of the events is changed after insertion of a new event somewhere in the middle or at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

[Currently](https://github.com/hynek/structlog/blob/0e24a574f2a0f402c45c33f68e5abe87f93d1459/src/structlog/dev.py#L250) `structlog.dev.ConsoleRenderer` does not have an option to disable key sorting.

The reason is that it's for humans and it's harder to orient yourself in a log when the key/value pairs are changing their position all the time.

In worst case, you have to hunt a key anew for every record with no real indication where it could be. With alphabetic order you at least know *where* to search for it.

I understand that it would be nicer to have certain new keys at the end, but ultimately it would mean that *every* key could potentially dance around all the time.